# clickhouse нагружает сервер до предела

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clickhouse

ClickHouse что-то делает в фоне и это загружает сервер до предела. Так уже второй день.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я выполнил `clickhouse restart` , он перезапустился и сразу продолжил эти процессы. как выяснить что это и остановить это?

никаких манипуляций с данными бд скрипты не делают сейчас.

Comment: Во-первых, это не процессы, а потоки. Во-вторых, на показанном вами скриншоте не видно, кто именно нагружает сервер (вы тактично обрезали столбец, показывающий нагрузку)